# Javascript created xml document formatting of empty elements

Tags: javascript, dom

Is it possible to control how an xml document is rendered by XMLSerializer when using your own namespace? Namely, when creating a document like this:

```
root = document.implementation.createDocument('hello-world', 'Something', null);
s = new XMLSerializer();
console.log(s.serializeToString(root));
```

The resulting xml from serializeToString is

```
<Something xmlns="hello-world"/>
```

Is there any way to change the formatting such that the output is instead

```
<Something xmlns="hello-world"></Something>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me to add an empty text node:

```
root.documentElement.appendChild(root.createTextNode(""));
```

With that line included, I get the output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><Something xmlns="hello-world"></Something>
```